Error: Deployment exceeded its progress deadline - Terraform Kubernetes Resource Deployment
I am deploying prometheus kubernetes resource using terraform locally. I am also using configmaps for loading configs into containers and volumes to map them. The issue is that when I am not using any volumes for containers, the resources are created and applied just fine, but when I use volume mounts and volumes, the deployment is times out giving the following error:
│ Error: Deployment exceeded its progress deadline
│ 
│   with kubernetes_deployment.prometheus,
│   on prometheus.tf line 112, in resource "kubernetes_deployment" "prometheus":
│  112: resource "kubernetes_deployment" "prometheus" {
│ 
╵
2024-04-24T17:00:41.106+0500 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF"
2024-04-24T17:00:41.108+0500 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes/2.29.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.29.0_x5 pid=112032
2024-04-24T17:00:41.108+0500 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited


Here is the config map definition in my code:
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "prometheus_config" {
  metadata {
    name = "prometheus-config"
  }
    data = {
        "prometheus.yml"= <<EOF

        */ steps omitted for brevity */

        EOF
    }
}

Here is the deployment part:
resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "prometheus" {
  metadata {
    name = "prometheus"
    labels = {
      app = "prometheus"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [kubernetes_config_map.prometheus_config]

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    update = "1h"
    delete = "20m"
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "prometheus"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "prometheus"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "prom/prometheus:latest"
          name  = "prometheus"
          port {
            container_port = 9090
          }
          
          #The problem is with this volume-mount according to my testing

          volume_mount {
            name = "prometheus-config"
            mount_path = "/etc/prometheus"
            sub_path   = "prometheus.yml"
          }
        }
        
        volume {
          name = "prometheus-config"
          config_map {
            name = kubernetes_config_map.prometheus_config.metadata[0].name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I have checked my config maps and they are created and applied when I use terraform apply, I have also verified them after they are created using kubectl describe configmap prometheus-config. The descriptions of config maps using terraform is same as when done in manual deployments(runs in manual).
The only difference between it working and not working is the code with volume and volume-mounts, commenting that part successfully applies my terraform files but that resource is not effective for me i.e it does not contain my configurations. While when i uncomment that code, terraform apply times out stating
[ERROR] vertex "kubernetes_deployment.prometheus" error: Deployment exceeded its progress deadline
Results when I comment out volume-mount and volumes block:
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

kubernetes_deployment_v1.prometheus: Creating...
kubernetes_deployment_v1.prometheus: Creation complete after 8s [id=default/prometheus]
Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.


You can add a timeout maybe: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment#timeouts. Also, I would definitely try with kubernetes_deployment_v1, that should be newer and could possibly fix some of the previous bugs.

Tried with timeout (20m) and kubernetes_deployment_v1, still facing same errors.

Would you mind adding the code blocks you use in their entirety to the question?

There is an option for progress deadline found here - though the default seems to be set at 600s which is a very high margin imo. You can still give it a go -- there is a slim chance that it might help here, in the scenario in which TF does not see any tangible progress in the span of 10 minutes (which would prompt the error you are receiving).
Since you are mounting a configMap and not something in the cloud that could theoretically take a while to spin up, I am suspecting that this would have to do with the declaration of the volume mount and possibly the volume itself.

Lose the subpath in your volume_mount -- that should typically be a path not a key name and in your case it's unnecessary since you only have the one key in the config map anyways.
Check that the configMap and deployment are in the same namespaces (otherwise the deployment will not find the Config Map solely by it's name and you likely need additional selectors)

